# Вывод Toast-сообщения в отдельном потоке. Android

Tags: java, android, android-toast

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: мне необходимо сделать в отдельном потоке паузу на `n` секунд и затем вывести `Toast` о том,что пауза окончена. Однако в отдельном потоке, как я уже понял (вот код моей попытки):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                            try {
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                thread.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pause finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

сделать это не представляется возможным. Однако в другом случае не понимаю, как мне тогда вывести этот `Toast`. Пробовал после потока, но сообщение выводится сразу же, т.к. пауза в одном потоке, а вывод сообщения в другом. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Что мешает сделать это в потоке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить доступ к основному потоку можно через `Handler`. Для этого вам надо создать его экземпляр:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
```

и вызвать его внутри другого потока в нужный момент:

```
...
h.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(context,"Pause finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
});
```